# After installing iOS 11 public beta, then deleting profile, will I receive the official release of iOS 10.3.3?

Tags: iphone, ios, beta

I'm currently using an iPhone 5S.

I installed the iOS 11 Public Beta a few days ago, and found that downgrading would risk my phone being stuck in recovery/DFU mode. I was wondering, if I deleted the profile (which would opt me out of receiving beta updates), would I get the update for the official release of iOS 10.3.3? And would I be able to install it, even when my phone is running on iOS 11?

Comment: Do [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203282#revert) from Apple answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't get an update to iOS 10.3.3, as this would amount to downgrading (not updating) your iOS, which isn't possible at all (except by restoring the iPhone from an old backup).